# Entity Framework Error In asp.net

Tags: entity-framework

**Class 1**

```
public partial class Profile : BaseEntity
{
    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Profile identifier
    /// </summary>
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the FullName
    /// </summary>
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Gender
    /// </summary>
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the DateofBirth
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime DateofBirth { get; set; }

}
```

**Class 2**

```
   public partial interface IProfileService
   {

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an Profile by profile identifier
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="profileid">profile identifier</param>
    /// <returns>Profile</returns>
     Profile GetProfileById(int profileid);


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all Profiles
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Profile collection</returns>
    List<Profile> GetAllProfiles();

   }
```

**Class 3**

```
  public partial class ProfileService : IProfileService
 {      
     /// <summary>
    /// Gets a profile by profile identifier
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="profileId">Profile identifier</param>
    /// <returns>profile</returns>
    public Profile GetProfileById(int profileid)
    {
        if (profileid == 0)
            return null;


        var query = from a in _context.Profilemasters
                    where a.ProfileId == profileid
                    select a;
        var profile = query.SingleOrDefault();

        return profile;
    }
  }
```

In Class 3 of return profile I get an error Message that "Cannot Implicitly Convert 'Data.Profilemaster' to 'Library.Profile'. Whareas Data.Profilemaster is an Entity table amd Library.Profile is Class ie. Class 1.

And when I use "MyContext.Profilemasters.AddObject(profile);" command to insert data I get another Error Message ie. "The Best Overloaded Method match for...."

Please help Me.

I am New in Entrity Framework.

Anybody has the Idea to solve this

Comment: How did you get your Profile class? How did you create mapping?

Comment: I am using all these Class in a Folder of the Project

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This .........

```
 public ModelTest GetTest(int id)
    {
        ModelTest ob = new ModelTest();
        var a = from r in _QEntities.Tests
                where r.id == id
                select r;
        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            ob.TestName = item.name;
            ob.TotalMarks = item.totalmarks;
        }

        return ob;
    }
```